# Import a huge CSV file into MySQL using a transaction

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, csv, sequelize.js

So the idea is to have this done using Node.JS, but any other programming language / platform might help, since the program should be simple.

**Problem:**

The program has to periodically download CSV files from an FTP server that need to be imported into MySQL.

**Challengues:**

- Those CSV files could sometimes contain millions of rows and we need to prevent memory exhaustion.
- If the import fails, there should be a rollback (SQL transaction?).
- We need to modify the data as is being imported.

I know about a NodeJS package called “fast-csv” which implements read streams to prevent high memory usage. This could potentially be the answer. The problem is that I do not find any library that would allow me to import the data into MySQL as a stream as well **and** using a transaction to allow rollback.

**Any ideas on what to use for this case? As I said, it does not necessarily have to be a NodeJS program.**

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) in a transaction. If your library doesn't have native support it see if you can just perform the queries directly to database.

Something along the lines of:

```
START TRANSACTION;

LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/yourfile.csv' INTO TABLE yourtable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';

UPDATE yourtable SET col1=col2*3;

COMMIT;
```

LOAD DATA itself allows basic manipulation already as part of the load. When executing the statements just check whether they succeeded or not and abort with `ROLLBACK` in case of failure.